# Matplotlib GridSpec without pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I need to create a rather complex Figure without pyplot - I would like to use gridspec, but how can I do it?

Target is a figure with N_COL * N_ROW Grid of axis, the last column occupies all rows.

example code:

```
N_COL = 3
N_ROW = 3

# just demo plt call
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10.0, 10.0))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(N_COL, N_ROW)


# how to mate the gs object with the figure. In pyplot I would use # plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
```

## I would like to create all axes as a list, except the last column which spans all rows.

Comment: but isn't your `fig` from `pyplot`?

Comment: @tom only in this example. Did not want to copy rather useless setup code. This does not run in a multithreaded environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I believe this is the OO way of using matplotlib:

```
fig.add_subplot(gs[0; :])
```

Comment: That's it. I stared so long at the damned pyplot interface that I was unable to see the solution.